# How to toggle select all/ deselect all checkbox when Listview Item click?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to toggle the **select all/deselect all checkbox**. Example:

If the total selected items in Listview is equal to the total items in listview then **select all/deselect all checkbox** will be check and if not then uncheck the **select all/deselect all checkbox**.

```
Dim c,listcount As Integer
listcount = ListView1.ListItems.Count

If c = listcount Then
    CheckBox1.Value = True
Else
    CheckBox1.Value = False
End If
```

My code for select and deselect all was fine, when you check or uncheck **select all/deselect all checkbox**, all the items in listview will also check or uncheck. The code above will toggle the **select all/deselect all checkbox** when the total selected items is equal to the total items in listview and it is triggered by checking or clicking the items in the listview but the problem is that it also triggers my code for the **select all/deselect all checkbox** which will result in unchecking all the list item in listview.

Can someone help me with this?

This is my code for **select all/ deselect all checkbox**:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
        'check if this is already check or not
        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            seldesel (True)
        Else
            seldesel (False)
        End If
    End Sub

Function seldesel(a As Boolean)
    listcount = ListView1.ListItems.Count
    For X = 1 To listcount
        ListView1.ListItems(X).Checked = a
    Next X
End Function
```

Comment: This post of mine may be of interest: http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-handler-class-multiple-controls/

Comment: I have no idea what is the relevance of your post in my question.

Comment: It's a way to manage a master/slave checkbox relationship in a userform. It sounds like that's what you're doing. If so, it doesn't matter whether it's Word or Excel. Does that make it any more relevant. (Remember, I'm just trying to be helpful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your CheckBox1_Click sub-routine from occurring, you could change the trigger from Click to CheckBox1_MouseDown. This way it will only run it's code when the user manual checks it with the Mouse.

Additionally, within MouseDown, the code runs before the box is actually checked. To fix your code change this line:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
```

Simply to this

```
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi codiplex, I updated my answer to fix the problem.

Comment: It works, I change the event of the <b>select all/deselect all checkbox</b> to mouse down but the problem is when I click the <b>select all/deselect all checkbox</b> , It will only check all the items in listview on the second click which is now it is uncheck and the items in listview is all check and if it is click again, it will check and the items in listview will be uncheck.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code from CheckBox1_MouseDown? I believe the error now lies there, and I'd love to help.

Comment: I updated my question above and added the code for my select all/ deselect all checkbox.

Comment: where did you get the checkbox2? I only have checkbox1

Comment: I was providing an example, while waiting for you to post your code. I made it relevant to your code, and we should be all set now.

Comment: Now it is not working dude. if I select all the items and uncheck one item in the listview, the select all/ deselect all checkbox will be uncheck but all of the items in listview is uncheck also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97464/discussion-between-jdb-dragon-and-codiplex).